# Transaction speeding up processing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, transactions

I was reading Agile Web Development With Rails, when I saw this piece of code:

```
Order.transaction do (1..100).each do |i|
    Order.create(:name => "Customer #{i}", :address => "#{i} Main Street",
      :email => "customer-#{i}@example.com", :pay_type => "Check")
end end
```

The author said: "Note that this code does all this work in one transaction. This isn’t precisely required for this activity but does speed up the processing".

So my question is, why the transaction speed up the processing of this block of code ?

Comment: Probably because there is some (possibly significant) overhead associated with a transaction. Therefore, if we can get everything done in one shot, we maximize our work/overhead ratio.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In both cases your rails apps makes 100 separate INSERT statements, but if you don't explicitly create a transaction then each update/insert sits inside its own transaction. Transactions are supposed to be ACID, in particular the D stands for durable: once a transaction has been committed there is a hard guarantee that it has been successfully written to disk, even if a power failure occurs 1 nanosecond later.

Committing a transaction thus requires that the writes be flushed which has an inherent cost (this can be mitigated by the right kind of RAID hardware). On the other hand when you are in the middle of one big transaction the database has no obligation to flush writes after the individual inserts.

Answer (score 0):

Because you have 100 creates happening in one interaction with the db instead of 100 separate interactions. Less hits to the db is usually quicker, because you reduce the cost specifically associated with the communication.

Comment: I see, so, this can be used like a rule ? Whenever I have lots of data to be saved in the db, like in this case, transactions should be used to speed up the processing ?

Comment: As a rule of thumb, yeah, I think you should try to minimize communications with the db. Though there are cases where you have to be careful. If you have have to make your query way more complex or instantiate a lot of unnecessary objects to avoid making extra db hits, in may not be worthwhile (both those examples are related to finds, though, not creates).